# Проблемы с доступом к сайту Requests

Tags: python, url, requests, beautiful-soup

Пишу скрипт на питоне, котолый должен заходить на
    `url = "http://zhldr3.ros.msudrf.ru/modules.php?name=sud_delo&G1_PARTS__NAMESS={name}&delo_id=1540005&op=sf".format(name = name)` и проверял наличие дел, заведённых на некоторого человека (на меня) P.S. Вмессто name должна быть фамилия). Я пишу такой код:

```
import requests as req
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

def get_html_by_name(name):
    url = "http://zhldr3.ros.msudrf.ru/modules.php?name=sud_delo&G1_PARTS__NAMESS={name}&delo_id=1540005&op=sf".format(name = name)
    print("Formed URL")
    r = req.get(url)
    print("Requested")
    print(r)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_html_by_name("Путин")
```

При запуске скрипта он формирует url и на это останавливается, дальше не идёт.  Т.е. просто замирает на выполнении реквэста.

При попытке получить доступ к сайту `http://zhldr3.ros.msudrf.ru/` Такая - же проблема. Пробывал добавить headers с User-Agent, но не помогло.
`print(req.get("http://google.com") )`
Возвращает `Resp 200`

Comment: Добавил все остальные headers, не помогло

Comment: Доступ к `http://msudrf.ru` так же ничем хороши не закончися

Comment: а что выдаёт print(req) и print(req.content)?

Comment: Выполнение до `    print("Requested")` недоходит. Он вечно пытается получить ответ от сервера.

Comment: Хотелось бы как то это реализовать без Selenium и его аналогов

Comment: Дотступ в обход ДНС - `req.get(79.133.87.8:80)` тоже не проходит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
res = r.get('http://zhldr3.ros.msudrf.ru/', timeout=100, headers={'User-Agent': 'some cool user-agent'})
```

Вот так сработало